# How to secure Laravel Glide library?

Tags: php, laravel

I've installed [Glide](https://glide.thephpleague.com/) to my laravel app and i'm tring to secure it from  [mass image-resize attacks](https://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/config/security/).

However i always get **Signature is not valid.**

This is my setup at **AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(Server::class, function($app) {

        $filesystem = $app->make("Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem");

        return ServerFactory::create([
            'response' => new LaravelResponseFactory(app('request')),
            'source' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache_path_prefix' => '.cache',
            'base_url' => 'img',
            'max_image_size' => 2000*2000,
        ]);

    });
}
```

In **ImageController.php** i generate the url like this

```
public static function thumbnailUrlBuilder($path) {

    $signkey = 'v-LK4WCdhcfcc%jt*VC2cj%nVpu+xQKvLUA%H86kRVk_4bgG8&CWM#k*b_7MUJpmTc=4GFmKFp7=K%67je-skxC5vz+r#xT?62tT?Aw%FtQ4Y3gvnwHTwqhxUh89wCa_';

    $urlBuilder = UrlBuilderFactory::create('/img/', $signkey);

    $url = $urlBuilder->getUrl($path, ["w" => 400, "h" => 400, "fit" => "crop"]);

    return $url;
}
```

And finally this is my show function in **ImageController.php** with the validation

```
public function show(Server $server, $path) {
    try {
        $signkey = 'v-LK4WCdhcfcc%jt*VC2cj%nVpu+xQKvLUA%H86kRVk_4bgG8&CWM#k*b_7MUJpmTc=4GFmKFp7=K%67je-skxC5vz+r#xT?62tT?Aw%FtQ4Y3gvnwHTwqhxUh89wCa_';

        SignatureFactory::create($signkey)->validateRequest($path, $_GET);

        $server->outputImage($path, $_GET);
    
    } catch (SignatureException $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong and how i can make this to work?

Please take note that this actually works but only if i remove the validation part, otherwise i get **Signature is not valid.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after hours of frustration i finally find it out.

Apparently what i've done so far was correct with the only exception the `$path` passed to `SignatureFactory` in the show function. Which requires the actual url. In my case the url path was something like this `/img/storage/images/2020.11/031.jpg` and i was passing `/storage/images/2020.11/031.jpg`.

So i changed my show function like the code sample below and everything works fine!

```
public function show(Server $server, $path) {
    try {
        $signkey = 'v-LK4WCdhcfcc%jt*VC2cj%nVpu+xQKvLUA%H86kRVk_4bgG8&CWM#k*b_7MUJpmTc=4GFmKFp7=K%67je-skxC5vz+r#xT?62tT?Aw%FtQ4Y3gvnwHTwqhxUh89wCa_';
        SignatureFactory::create($signkey)->validateRequest("/img/$path", $_GET);

        $server->outputImage($image, $_GET);
    
    } catch (SignatureException $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

Of course we can change `->validateRequest("/img/$path", $_GET);` to be dynamic but this is just a demo.